# Xcode 6: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I just accidentally deleted a framework but I can't figure out which one it is, nor do I know if adding it back will simply solve the problem. This is the error message that I'm getting:

ld: cannot link directly with /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib.  Link against the umbrella framework 'System.framework' instead. for architecture i386
clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure theres a simple solution, I just cannot figure it our for the life of me!

Thanks!

Comment: Was your question answered?  If so, please take a minute to accept it, to mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've linked directly against `libdyld.dylib` which isn't necessary as it's part of one of the core frameworks. Remove it and it should compile fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

Source control is the simple solution.  You'd be able to diff your project to see what (framework) changed, or revert it to an earlier (working) state.

If you aren't using source control (you didn't check the 'Use Git' box when you created your project), here's how to start using it with your existing project.

Open up a terminal window, and cd to the project directory -- it's the one with the *ProjectName*.xcodeproj directory. Once there, type:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Restart Xcode. The repository will now be visible in Xcode, and you can commit or discard changes via the project navigator, and compare revisions via the Version editor.